# Can we update a Netsuite "Custom Record type" field by clicking a button?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a Suitelet script to create a form, there I pull the information contained in a  "Custom Record type" as the default value for the form fields.
Also create a ClientScript for the Suitelet form with the functions that are executed by clicking a button.
The function works, but I don't know how to update the information of the custom record type.
Here is part of my code:

Suitelet:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 */

 define(['N/record', 'N/search', 'N/ui/serverWidget'],
 function(record, search, serverWidget) { 
     function onRequest(context) { 
        try {
            if (context.request.method === 'GET') {

                var form = serverWidget.createForm({
                    title: 'SKU Information'
                });

                form.clientScriptFileId  =  3060; 
   
                //create fields groups to organize the fields
                var itemgroup = form.addFieldGroup({
                    id : 'itemgroup',
                    label : 'Next item SKU Number'
                });

                var usegroup = form.addFieldGroup({
                    id : 'usegroup',
                    label : 'Who is using this?'
                });
                
               //Add the fields
                var skufield = form.addField({
                    id: 'skufield',
                    type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                    label: 'SKU Number',
                    container: 'itemgroup'
                });
                skufield.isMandatory = true;
   
                // create a field with the user using this numbers when clicking the button
                var whousingskunumber = form.addField({
                    id: 'namefield',
                    type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                    label: 'User:',
                    container: 'usegroup'
                });
                whousingskunumber.updateDisplayType({
                    displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.DISABLED
                });

                var usingsince = form.addField({
                    id: 'sincefield',
                    type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                    label: 'Using since',
                    container: 'usegroup'
                });
                usingsince.updateDisplayType({
                    displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.DISABLED
                });

                // Add the buttons
                form.addSubmitButton({
                    label: 'Update Number'
                });
                form.addResetButton({
                    label: 'Cancel'
                });
                
                var useNumber = form.addButton({
                    label: 'Use this number',
                    id: 'useNumber',
                    functionName: 'useNumberFunction',
                });
                var releaseNumber = form.addButton({
                    label: 'Release usage',
                    id: 'relaseNumber',
                    functionName: 'relaseNumberFunction',
                });

               context.response.writePage(form);
               
           } else {
               // Section Four - Output - Used in all sections
               var delimiter = /\u0001/;
               var skuField = context.request.parameters.skufield;
               var whoField = context.request.parameters.whofield;
   
               var ccField = context.request.parameters.cctypefield;
   
               context.response.write('You have entered:'
                   + '<br/>  New SKU Number: '+ whoField + skuField);
            }

            var skuNumObj = search.lookupFields({
               type: 'customrecordere_lw_lastskunum',
               id: 2,
               columns: ['custrecord_ere_lw_usingsince', 'custrecordere_lw_nextskunum', 'custrecord_ere_lw_whousingskunum']
           });
           
           var usingSince = skuNumObj.custrecord_ere_lw_usingsince;
           var whoIsUsing = skuNumObj.custrecord_ere_lw_whousingskunum;
           var nextSku = skuNumObj.custrecordere_lw_nextskunum;
           
           skufield.defaultValue = nextSku;
           whousingskunumber.defaultValue = 'Nobody';
           usingsince.defaultValue = 'You can use it!';

        } catch (error) {
            log.error({title: 'Failed to get items to update', details: error});
        }

     }
 return {
     onRequest: onRequest
 };

});
```

ClientScript

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
//Noslen Pena

define(['N/runtime', 'N/currentRecord', 'N/ui/dialog', 'N/search'],
    function (runtime, currentRecord, dialog, search) {
        function pageInit(context){
            try {
                

            } catch (error) {
                log.error({title: 'Failed initializing', details: error});
            }
        }

     function useNumberFunction(){
         try {
            var skuNumObj = search.lookupFields({
                type: 'customrecordere_lw_lastskunum',
                id: 2,
                columns: ['custrecord_ere_lw_usingsince', 'custrecordere_lw_nextskunum', 'custrecord_ere_lw_whousingskunum']
            });
            var nextSku = skuNumObj.custrecordere_lw_nextskunum[0].value;
            skuNumObj.custrecordere_lw_nextskunum[0].value = Number(nextSku)+1;

            dialog.alert({
                title: "Information",
                message: 'Remember to unlock after you have used'
            });
            context.skufield.updateDisplayType({
                displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.DISABLED
            });
         } catch (error) {
            log.error({title: 'Failed clicking the button', details: error});
         }
     }

     function relaseNumberFunction(){
        dialog.alert({
            title: "Thank you!",
            message: "Remember to update the number and save the changes"
        });
        record.namefield.setValue('Nobody');
        log.debug({title: 'liberaron el uso', details:'Nobody is using the number now'})
     }

    return {
        pageInit : pageInit,
        useNumberFunction    : useNumberFunction,
        relaseNumberFunction : relaseNumberFunction

    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, The way to save the changes or submit a new value to the custom record type is like this:

```
           var id = record.submitFields({
                type: 'customrecordere_lw_lastskunum',
                id: 2,
                values: {
                    custrecord_ere_lw_usingsince     : since,
                    custrecord_ere_lw_whousingskunum : username
                },
                options: {
                    enableSourcing: false,
                    ignoreMandatoryFields : true
                }
            });
```